# Product of discontinuous function with zero

Tags: calculus

This is going to be breathtakingly stupid, but it's one of those things I've forgotten: if we have a function like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -x^2}}$ and we multiply it by zero, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\cdot 0$, IS the product ALWAYS zero, or do we still have a problem at the pole x = 1?

Comment: I wouldn't say "breathtaking"...but close: the zero function multiplied by *any* function is the zero function, which is defined *everywhere* and, thus, has no poles.